# Method is not working in my jsp page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

```
var values= {Title :title , BannerImg : bannerimgsrc ,Banneralt :bodyimgalt ,nbLink : navBarEditorLinks ,LinksEditor : links, Address : addresses};



var editorTXT =JSON.stringify(values);----This is my json String which i get when i submit my html form.I am extracting all the values from the form on submission. 
            alert(editorTXT);
```

Once I get this json object I am trying to post to server using .post or .ajax on click of  save button. But when I click on save this method is completely ignored. Please suggest me how to make it work. I am using jquery 1.6.2.js lib. Please suggest me if my ajax method syntax is wrong.

```
jQuery.ajax({type:"POST", url : " mailMgtCntrlS/init",
data : { filename: filename,
    cmd: cmd, 
    token: token,                                
partitionid: partitionid                                 content_desc: content_desc,                                 EditorDefault: editorTXT},                             
 success :function(){                                   alert('successful');                                        var response = result.split(":");                                       document.saveNewsletterForm.token.value = result[1];
        },                                  dataType:'json'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
 type:"POST", 
 url : " mailMgtCntrlS/init", 
 dataType:'json',
 data :"JSONFile=" + { filename: filename, cmd: cmd, token: token, partitionid: partitionid content_desc: content_desc, EditorDefault: editorTXT},
 success :function(result,msg){ 
   alert(msg); 
   alert(result.filename); // if you respose same with your post
   //var response = result.split(":"); 
   //document.saveNewsletterForm.token.value = result[1]; 
 }
});
```

i'm suggesting

1. give parameter what do you want, example "JSONFile" in data option `$.ajax` see my answer code
2. getParameter in server example `request.getParams("JSONFile");//this is in java`

on your JSON try to change like this

```
{ 
    "filename": "filename", 
    "cmd": "cmd", 
    "token": "token", 
    "partitionid": "partitionid", 
    "content_desc": "content_desc", 
    "EditorDefault": "editorTXT"  
}
```